# set default value to (select all) in ssrs

Tags: ssrs-2008

hi i want to set the default value as zero to parameter in ssrs when the clinent is check to (Select All) then the parameter value become zero and the data set get the parameter value as '0'

Answer (score 0):

Uh, sounds like you're wanting to change the behaviour of the 'Select All' option in SSRS multi-value parameters. Most people do want to change that, because its kind of annoying.

I think you're saying that when people click 'Select all' you want to select a single 'magic value' like 0 instead.

Thats not possible in the default SSRS Report Manager, but if you code up your own interface you might be able to do it.

For details of ways to add a 'magic' value that represents '--All--' in an SSRS multi-value picklist, see my blog post:
http://www.codeulike.com/2012/03/ssrs-multi-value-parameters-with-less.html